# run the progress bar in another thread

Tags: c#

I am trying to show a progress bar when I click a button, and hide it when the work is finished. But when I show the progress bar in the button event handler, it doesn't work and  is only shown after the work is done.

Here is my code:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            loadingprgoress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }));

    int usresult, psresult;

    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader data = null;
    String myQueryEdit1 = @"SELECT Username, Password FROM [dbo].[Table]";
    com.CommandText = myQueryEdit1;
    com.Connection = con;
    data = com.ExecuteReader();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int newrnd = rnd.Next(1, 100);

    if (data.Read())
    {

        string userhash = GenerateHashWithSalt(data["Username"].ToString(), newrnd.ToString());
        string passhash = GenerateHashWithSalt(data["Password"].ToString(), newrnd.ToString());
        string userhash1 = GenerateHashWithSalt("admin", newrnd.ToString());
        string passhash1 = GenerateHashWithSalt(pasbox.Password, newrnd.ToString());

        usresult = userhash.CompareTo(userhash1);
        psresult = passhash.ToString().CompareTo(passhash1);
        if (usresult == 0 && psresult == 0)
        {
            con.Close();
            dental_main_Window neww = new dental_main_Window();
            neww.Show();
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            pasbox.Password = "";
        }

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
           {
               loadingprgoress.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
           }));
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at background worker (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

It allows you to run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread. 
During the background computation, you can raise the **ProgressChanged** event to notify the UI and update the ProgressBar accordingly:

```
private BackgroundWorker _worker;

public Form1(string[] args)
{
    InitializeComponent();


    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_WorkCompleted;
    _worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    _worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;


}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DoStuff();
}
private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
private void worker_WorkCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _running = false;
    UpdateUi();
}

private bool DoStuff()
{
        //...
        _worker.ReportProgress(20);
        //...
        _worker.ReportProgress(20);

        return true;

}

private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your UI thread is doing all the work (accessing the database) and until it's done, it can't process any more messages (like showing the progress bar).

You need to do the opposite, show the progress bar in the UI thread without BeginInvoke and do the database accesss in another thread. When you the other thread finishes, you need to do a BeginInvoke on the UI thread to hide the progress bar.

Here is another important note: this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke doesn't spawn a thread. It "pushes" the command to the queue of the UI thread because all UI operations must be executed from the UI thread.

Here is what you do:

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

1. Show progress bar
2. Use Tasks to start your background process
3. Add a continuation task to your first task to send the message to the UI that the process has completed
4. In the continuation task use this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke so that the UI staff happens on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

UI in WPF needs to execute on the UI thread. And you recognise that because I can see you using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to interact with your progress window.

Your problem though is that you are executing your long-running task also on the UI thread. When you do that you don't give the progress window an opportunity to operate. The thread is consumed by the long-running task and is thus unable to service the UI.

The solution is to execute the long-running task away from the UI thread.

Comment: when i am doing that, it get error, the object is own to current thread and can not be accessible with another thread.\

Comment: Then you need to fix that problem. It doesn't change the fact that you need to execute your long-running tasks away from the UI thread.